# Is there any way to open Chrome at full screen and with navigation buttons?

Tags: google-chrome

Basically I need to open a Chrome full screen window with the navigation buttons.

Is there a parameter to the kiosk command that can do that?

I can't find anything in Chronium's documentation.

I know there's an add-on to do that on Firefox, but I need to run Chrome.

Comment: Why Chrome? If you can open up this requirement, your life would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 5):

Chrome does not have navigation bar while in full screen.  This is by design.  A lot of [people petitioned this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8022), but this feature hasn't been changed.

You can use hot keys to navigate back, forth, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch tabs, but you cannot navigate to a different URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Chrome extension: [Full Screen Helper for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/llphjdgpfodiaafmnllhofinfjjnmdip)

It provides back/forward buttons, address bar, and the opened tabs.

Comment: Dead link, please update.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend here, first answer:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=4f25589f0caf9781&hl=en

Chrome doesn't have a status bar, even when not fullscreen!

Comment: Blarg. I meant navigation buttons not status bar.